# Magento 2 : custom shipping method not appearing on checkout page

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

I have installed an extension
https://onboard.hub-box.com/download/magento2-extension

in this extension there is a shipping method "Free In-store Collection"
i have enabled it from backend but in frontend not appearing on select shipping method section.

any thoughts what can be checked to know the issue with it ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can verify this things :

1. Extension install properly and configured properly from the admin.
2. Extension enable for store/website level, if applicable.
3. Confirm your current cart full fill all the conditions of that shipping method like Total, Allowed Counties etc.